# Can a Docker volume also be a bind mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-volume

In Docker documentation, there is a very clear distinction between a bind mount and a volume.

Yet, I stumbled upon this in a compose file, in the root-level `volumes` element.

```yaml
volumes:
  myvolume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/my/host/folder'
```

I am pretty sure this is a volume, because it is visible in `docker volume ls`.

But the `bind` option suggests that this is also a bind mount.

Is my assumption correct? I.e. this is a kind of bind mount that binds to a docker volume rather than a container's internal folder (so, as a matter of fact, there are two "bindings" in place)?

How does this work from an operative system standpoint?

Does this still leverage the benefits of using a Docker volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring Docker for a moment, on a Linux host you can run `mount --bind /old/dir /new/dir` to make two directories have the same underlying disk storage.  This has the same properties as a Docker bind mount; if you write to `/new/dir` it's also visible in `/old/dir`, and if anything was in `/new/dir` before the mount it's hidden.  I believe it's possible to also write this as `mount -o bind ...` (though [this copy of **mount**(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) doesn't document it).

For a named volume, Docker's default setup internally is to create a directory in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and then bind-mount that into the container.  But you can [manually create a volume using mount options](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#block-storage-devices) as well, with documented uses being to mount a physical disk as a Docker volume or to mount a remote network drive.

This syntax you show combines these two options.  You "manually create a volume using mount options", but those mount options actually set up a bind mount.

This has a couple of minor advantages.  Other parts of your Compose setup don't need to know the host path, only the Compose-local volume name.  If you make a mistake and the host directory doesn't exist, you'll get an error rather than the directory being created.

This also brings with Docker's confusing and non-standard behavior about copying contents into new volumes: if the directory is empty, but only then, and only for Docker named volumes and not any other kind of mount, image content will be copied in.  `docker volume rm` won't actually delete the host-directory content, only the mount point inside the Docker private filesystem space.

For almost all uses I'd go with the inline-path syntax, in a specific container `volumes: ['./dir:/container/path']`.  Since Compose can translate relative paths you can use `./dir` to use a directory within your project tree, which minimizes the portability concerns around hard-coding host directories.